# Deduce alternate series test from Abel’s theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that the alternate series test can be deduced from Abel’s theorem.

I know that Abel's theorem is

Abel's Theorem

Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be two sequences of real numbers such that

• $(a_n)$ is non-increasing and tends to $0$,

• There exists $M \in R$ such that, for any $n \in N$, $| \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k| \leq M.$

Then the series $\sum_n a_n b_n$ converges

But How to Show deduction of alternate series test ?

Comment: You are talking about Dirichlet's test not Abel's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an alternating series $\sum a_nb_n$ where $a_n \to 0$ is non-increasing and $b_n = (-1)^n$.

Show that the sequence of partial sums $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kb_k$ satifies the Cauchy criterion.

Using summation by parts,

$$|S_m - S_n|= \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} a_kb_k\right|= \left|a_mB_m- a_{n+1}B_n + \sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1} (a_k-a_{k+1})B_k\right|,$$

where

$$B_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k.$$

Note that $B_n$ is bounded, and there exists $B > 0$ such that $|B_n| \leq B$ for all $n$.  In this case we can take $B=1$.

Since, $(a_n)$ is a non-increasing sequence converging to $0$, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that if $n > N$, then we have $a_n < \epsilon/(2B)$.

Hence,

$$|S_m - S_n| \leq |a_m||B_m|+ |a_{n+1}||B_n| + \sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1} |a_k-a_{k+1}||B_k|\\ \leq B\left(a_m+ a_{n+1} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1} (a_k-a_{k+1})\right)=2Ba_{n+1}.$$

Thus, for any $\epsilon > 0$ , if $n > N$ we have

$$|S_m - S_n| \leq 2Ba_{n+1}< 2B\frac{\epsilon}{2B}= \epsilon,$$

and the sequence of partial sums is a Cauchy sequence and, hence, convergent.

Alternatively,

Note that for some $N \in \mathbf{N}$ we have $a_n < \epsilon$ when $n \geqslant N$ and

$$|S_m - S_n|= \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} (-1)^ka_k\right|= a_{n+1} - (a_{n+2} - a_{n+3}) - ... \leqslant a_{n+1} < \epsilon$$

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using  summation by parts ?

Comment: Yes -- I reconstructed the proof of the Dirichlet test to prove the alternating series test -- but I'll add a simpler argument.

Comment: The alternating series test is easily proved as shown in the part I added. Originally I was trying to interpret the question " ... deduce ... from Abel's theorem".  Obviously an alternating series satisfies the hypotheses of Abel's theorem, but I thought you wanted to understand the connection.

Comment: I think Now I can try different cases on my own. If I will be having any problem THen I will comment here